# Is there a way to change my URL to point to a custom port?

Tags: docker, web, url, server, port

As stated in the title, i would like to change (internaly) my URL from:

https://subdomain.example.tech:8081/

to something like:

https://subdomain.example.tech/something/

Is it actually possible? (it's a Docker)
thanks for your answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a web server/load balancer which handles the requests.

So, you should handle it on its configurations, Not in `Docker`.

For example, if you use `nginx` so:

```
server {
listen 8081;
server_name subdomain.example.tech;
return 301 https://subdomain.example.tech/$request_uri;
}
```